# I have problem in back office of prestashop 1.7.5.1

Tags: prestashop, backoffice

I install prestashop 1.7.5.1 (the final version) in my local server (in wamp server - Apache 2.4.37 - PHP 7.2.14 - MySQL 5.7.24). My front office is ok, but all pages in my back office have problems. For example, in the   picture below, My computer is not connected to the Internet.

[image: problems in back office]

but when I connect my computer to the internet my back office all is ok as shown in the picture below:

[image: all ok in back office]

as if jquery  or css is not loaded properly in my back office (when My computer is not connected to the Internet).I want work offline on my shop.

Please help me, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remember Prestashop use Bootstrap Framework, if you are offline the CDN wont receive the correct communication, you can see the result

You can try to use the Maintenance mode, to work offline.

Answer (score 0):

This comes because of Prestashop backoffice use some external files of css and images.
To work offline you installed it in your website admin directory.
You can find those external link in your css admin file your_directory/admin_folder/themes/default/css/admin-theme.css